# How to analyse serial brain sections probed for different proteins (ttests and potenial issue of independance)

Tags: t-test, independence, resampling

**Generic scenario**: Brains have been collected from two different populations. They then have been cut into thin sections (serially) for the purpose of looking at the expression of proteins in specific areas. The sections are thin enough that we can take multiple sections which will correspond to the same brain area (so we can consider them equivalent for the scenarios below).

**Scenario 1** (same protein different regions): We want to look at the expression of protein A in 5 different brain regions. So we take a section from each region, from each brain that was collected. It is generally considered that any changes in each brain region are due to a direct effect of treatment instead of a direct or indirect consequence of changes in the 3 regions.

The generic approach is to do three separate t-tests (1 for each region), using the generic alpha threshold of 0.05 and the data appears to be normally distributed with identical standard deviations. How valid is this considering all results have come from the same source, would a p-value adjustment method be sufficient to correct for this? Or is something like a repeated-measures multifactorial design required?

**Scenario 2** (multiple proteins but same region): Let's say I want to look at proteins B through to F in one brain region. So we take 5 separate sections (corresponding to the same region) to look for each protein separately. Again the untested assumption is that any effects seen are due to treatment alone.

Again the generic response is three t-tests, generic threshold and data appear to be normally distributed with equal variances. Again do we need a p-value correction method to reflect that each section has come from a common source or is a more complex test required?

As a disclaimer, I have very little statistical training (though this may be more than others I know with a similar background) and it has mainly focused on frequentist statistical methods.